# CC appears on next page with scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

The `\cc{}` (**Kopie an**) appears on the next page no matter how short the letter itself is.

```
\documentclass[
    firsthead=true,
    fromalign=right,
    fromrule=afteraddress,
    symbolicnames=true,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
% = FROM =
\setkomavar{fromname}{From}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{adress}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{xxx}
% = TO =
\setkomavar{toname}{To}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{adress}
% =
\setkomavar{place}{Ort}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}

% = Letter =
\begin{letter}{}
    \opening{Sehr geehrter}
        xxx
    \closing{Mit freundlichsten Grüßen}
\end{letter}
\cc{Mr Doe}
\end{document}
```

The output

[image: Output pages]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move `\cc{Mr Doe}` before `\end{letter}` ...

See the corrected MWE

```
\documentclass[
    firsthead=true,
    fromalign=right,
    fromrule=afteraddress,
    symbolicnames=true,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
% = FROM =
\setkomavar{fromname}{From}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{adress}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{xxx}
% = TO =
\setkomavar{toname}{To}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{adress}
% =
\setkomavar{place}{Ort}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}

% = Letter =
\begin{letter}{}
    \opening{Sehr geehrter}
        xxx
    \closing{Mit freundlichsten Grüßen}
    \cc{Mr Doe} % <=====================================================
\end{letter}
%\cc{Mr Doe} % <========================================================
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting letter]